# Pulling certain values(Name, Email, Phone number) from text file

Tags: java, regex, email, string

I have a whole bunch of emails that I need pull information from.  I recently took on a site that stored all their contact information for customers in emails.  They want to start storing this in a database.  I'm working with Java trying to pull this information out.  I'm kind of stuck.

I have been able to load the emails themselves, but have been unable to *extract* the information. Here's an example email:

```
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> Name: Person's Name
> Phone:=20
> Email: test@testperson.com
> Street:=20
> City:=20
> State:=20
> Zip:=20
> Country:=20
> Arrival: 15 Nov 2010
> Departure: 22 Nov 2010
> Message: This is a message
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> Name: Second Person
> Phone:=555-5554
> Email: test@testpsdf.com
> Street:=1234 Main St.
> City:=20
> State:=20
> Zip:=23412
> Country:=20
> Arrival: 15 Nov 2010
> Departure: 22 Nov 2010
> Message: This is a message
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to pull everywhere there is not an `=20`.  I need to somehow get all this information into a table or CSV file so I can import it into a mysql database.

Edit:

This is actually what the file looks more like

```
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> Name: Erin 
> Phone: 401-
> Email: eri
> Street: 737
> City: Paw
> State: 
> Zip: 02
> Country: USA
> Arrival: 17 Jul 2011
> Departure: 23 Jul 2011
> Message: I .=20
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>=20
> A representative will be in touch shortly.
> Thank You,
>
>=20
Begin forwarded message:

> From: 
> Date: July 8, 2010 12:35:13 PM EDT
> To: 
> Subject: Thank you for completing our contact form!
>=20
> Thank you for completing our contact form! We received the following =
information from you:
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> Name: Ludd
> Phone:=20
> Email: aedu
> Street: 25
> City: Signal 
> State: 
> Zip: 
> Country: USA
> Arrival: 25 Nov 2010
> Departure: 30 Nov 2010
> Message: Not sure if 
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>=20
> A representative will be in touch shortly.
> Thank You,
>
>=20
Begin forwarded message:

> From: 
> Date: July 8, 2010 11:29:49 AM EDT
> To: 
> Subject: Thank you for completing our contact form!
>=20
> Thank you for completing our contact form! We received the following =
information from you:
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> Name: Stephanie
> Phone: 41
> Email: sgor
> Street: 2-
> City: 
> State: On
> Zip:  1J6
> Country: 
> Arrival: 18 Aug 2010
> Departure: 21 Aug 2010
> Message:=20
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>=20
> A representative will be in touch shortly.
> Thank You,

>=20
Begin forwarded message:

> From: 
> Date: July 8, 2010 11:16:36 AM EDT
> To:
> Subject: Thank you for completing our contact form!
>=20
> Thank you for completing our contact form! We received the following =
information from you:
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> Name: Stacey 
> Phone: 001
> Email: staceymou
> Street: 60 
> City: New York
> State: NY
> Zip: 0
> Country: USA
> Arrival: 10 Dec 2010
> Departure: 14 Dec 2010
> Message: Looking to reserve 
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method that extracts all such headers to a `Map<String, String>`. It uses Google's [Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) to simplify things a lot:

```
public static Map<String, String> readValuesFromFile(final File f)
    throws IOException{

    final Splitter splitter =
        Splitter.on(':').trimResults().omitEmptyStrings();

    final Map<String, String> map = Maps.newHashMap();

    for(final String line : 

        Lists.transform(
            Files.readLines(f, Charsets.UTF_8),
            new Function<String, String>(){

                @Override
                public String apply(final String input){
                    return input != null && input.startsWith("> ")
                        ? input.substring(2)
                        : input;
                }

    })){

        if(line.startsWith("---")){
            break;
        }
        final String[] items =
            Iterables.toArray(splitter.split(line), String.class);
        if(items.length == 2 && !items[1].startsWith("=20")){
            map.put(items[0], items[1]);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Hey man.  Thank you so much for your help.  I've been messing a little more with your method but can't make it work exactly as I need it to.  It seems to only get the last entry. Say I have 3 of those entries it only gets the last one, not multiple entries.  I'm not sure why that is happening.  I had to take the line.startsWith("---")) out because it would not work.  Any ideas?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @dham about `line.startsWith()` sorry, didn't see that the header also was dashes. also, you didn't mention that you had multiple values. What do you men: multiple rows with the same prefix or multiple values in one row. Please append that to your question

Comment: @dham Oh, I think I get you, you are reading more than one file per method call. Don't do that: one map represents one file. Keep a List of Maps.

Comment: Hey man.  I updated the original post with an example.  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Read the file until you get that ">-------" line.
Read every line (`BufferedReader.readLine()`), find the position of ":" in it, take the part of the line before and past it (use `String.indexOf()`, `String.substring()`, `String.trim()`). Now you have a name of field and its value. Unless value is "=20", put it in a database or a CSV record.

If you encounter a ">-------" line again, the record is over. You can easily detect it by the fact that there's no ':' in it either.